# How can I hide certain values of CCK on node view page?

Tags: 6, entities, theming

When a cck field can have multiple values I would like to hide certain values to print on node template.

For example, 
If `field_example` has the value `"red" "blue" "yellow" "black" "white"`  I need to hide `"black" and "white"` and print only the rest on template file.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Field Permission module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions). It allows to give different access rights to different roles per field.

Comment: Thanks, but it can control only on the field level but not the value of fields..